# How to make child alignParentRight in RelativeLayout which is set to wrap_content?

Tags: android

In `RelativeLayout` which is set to `wrap_content`, child can not be set to `layout_alignParentRight="true"`.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

---

I found a solution here:
[       A LinearLayout (vertical) (wrap_content)                                ]
    [ B(child of A) RelativeLayout (match_parent)                   ]
        [ D(child of B) TextView layout_alignParentRight="true" ]
        [ c(child of A) TextView -> which A is try to wrap_content of ]

I know that "A is wrap_content then B is match_parent" is not good, but somehow it works.

Comment: No you can't do that If parent is wrap_content

Comment: Thanks. I konw that child can't set layout_alignParentRight, I just wonder if these is someway could do the same effect

Comment: I think giving fix size of width/height to the Relative layout you can set layout_alignParentRight="true" to child. Just try.

Comment: @anddev thanks, I'm sure it works, but I need the parent to be wrap_content.

Comment: @user3069380 Have you tried with layout_gravity="right"?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happens,

Example 1

```
[        Relative layout (match_parent)                ]
                                   [child aligned right]
```

Example 2

```
[Rel. Layout (wrap_content)]
[child has nowhere to align]
```

You may be able to set the width to 0dp and set the weight to 1, making the relative layout fill it's parent.

Example 3

```
[                    Some layout parent                      ]
[ some other view ][relative layout with width 0dp, weight 1 ]
                                         [child aligned right]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it into wrap content but does not have the effect that you want probably, So make the RelativeLayout `match_parent`.

Comment: but somehow, I need the parent to be wrap_content

Comment: You can set it programmatically if you want. I mean set the width of your RelativeLayout to be relativeLayoutParrent.getWidth()-restOftheViewSum.getWith().after that set the child view addRule(Relativelayout.ALIGN_PARRENT_RIGHT)... and set relativelayoutparams to your childview